# iOS SIGBART Error after extracting some of my code to an Private Cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I recently wanted to extract the Core functionality of my iOS App, into an private CocoaPod, to use it in an AppExtension and for an tvOS App in the future.

I started by creating a private Pod, using pod lib create.
I then moved the source Files in Finder over to the location in my newly created CocoaPod, and included them using the "Add Files to Project" function of Xcode. I edited the source files to work in a Pod, for example: adding public to Classes and Functions.

After Fixing all Bugs, I tried to start my app on the Device. And now it's giving me a SIGBART when trying to decode an Object using NSKeyedArchiver, giving the following **Error message**:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (*myProject*.User) for key (root); the class may be defined in
>   source code or a library that is not linked'"

The code that executes the decode and the Class User are both in the Pod.
Picture of Code

```
    public var currentUser:User? {
    get {
        if let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: Keys.CurrentUser) as? Data {
            NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(User.self, forClassName: "User")
            if let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as? User {
                return user
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I think I crashed my project during the copyProcess of the Files, and now the App gets confused where the Class is located or something.

Any help is really appreciated!
Thank you :)

[Podfile of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utnbS.png)

[Podspec of private Pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC0k0.png)

Comment: Maybe by trying to delete the app on your device and running it again?

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. Didn't thought of that!
Can I somehow mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Since I'm not sure why, I won't post an answer right now. My guess, is that `encodeWithCoder:`/`decodeWithCoder:` is kind of "versioned", and since you used it from two different places, it couldn't decode with the previous encode.